# Problems deploying with Capistrano (symlink error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, passenger

When trying to deploy to my staging server I`m getting an error when what it seems like the moment at which Capistrano is trying to create a database.yml file.

Currently I have the database.yml file in my gitIgnore file (I`ve tried with it included).

I've never had this problem before so I don`t really know how to go about debugging this issue.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

**Deployment Log:**

```
executing `deploy:symlink'
  * executing "rm -f /home/deploy/example.com/current && ln -s /home/deploy/example.com/releases/20130219164028 /home/deploy/example.com/current"
    servers: ["example.com"]
    [example.com] executing command
    command finished in 1893ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:symlink'
  * executing `deploy:copy_database_yml'
  * executing "ln -s /home/deploy/example.com/shared/data/development /home/deploy/example.com/releases/20130219164028/solr/data/live"
    servers: ["example.com"]
    [example.com] executing command
    command finished in 1867ms
  * executing "ln -s /home/deploy/example.com/shared/config/database.yml /home/deploy/example.com/releases/20130219164028/config/database.yml"
    servers: ["example.com"]
    [example.com] executing command
 ** [out :: example.com] ln: creating symbolic link `/home/deploy/example.com/releases/20130219164028/config/database.yml'
 ** [out :: example.com] : File exists
    command finished in 2086ms
*** [deploy:symlink] rolling back
*** no previous release to rollback to, rollback of symlink skipped
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deploy/example.com/releases/20130219164028; true"
    servers: ["example.com"]
    [example.com] executing command
    command finished in 2640ms
failed: "env PATH=/home/deploy/example.com/bin:$PATH GEM_HOME=/home/deploy/example.com/gems sh -c 'ln -s /home/deploy/example.com/shared/config/database.yml /home/deploy/example.com/releases/20130219164028/config/database.yml'" on example.com
```

**The contents of my deploy.rb file**

```
set :stages, %w(staging integration live)
set :default_stage, "staging"
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
require "bundler/capistrano"

default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :application, "Example"
set :use_sudo, false
set :keep_releases, 5

# If you aren't using Subversion to manage your source code, specify
# your SCM below:
#set :people, 'root'
#set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Restarting mod_rails with restart.txt"
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => {:no_release => true} do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  [:start, :stop].each do |t|
    desc "#{t} task is a no-op with mod_rails"
    task t, :roles => :app do
      ;
    end
  end

  # Avoid keeping the database.yml configuration in git.
  desc "task to create a symlink for the database files."
  task :copy_database_yml do
    run "ln -s #{shared_path}/data/development #{release_path}/solr/data/live"
    run "ln -s #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
    run "rm -rf #{release_path}/public/photos"
    run "ln -s #{shared_path}/public/photos #{release_path}/public/photos"
    run "rm -rf #{release_path}/public/hobby_photos"
    run "ln -s #{shared_path}/public/hobby_photos #{release_path}/public/hobby_photos"
    run "chmod 777 -R #{release_path}"
    #run "cd #{release_path}; bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=staging"
    #    run "cd #{release_path}/ & rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=staging"
  end

end

after "deploy:symlink", "deploy:copy_database_yml"
```

Comment: Looks like you are using some custom capistrano recipes for handling database.yml, please post them

Comment: Just added the contents of my deploy.rb file, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have answer right in front of your eyes.

```
** [out :: example.com] ln: creating symbolic link `/home/deploy/example.com/releases/20130219164028/config/database.yml'
** [out :: example.com] : File exists
```

Modify your deploy:copy_database_yml to remove symbolic link first, or to create it only if it doesn't exist.
BTW this task does much more than its name suggest, which is bad.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem of Capistrano when creating the symbolic links.

Try to comment the roles in your deploy.rb file:

```
#role :app, %w{deploy@yourhost.com}
#role :web, %w{deploy@yourhost.com}
#role :db,  %w{deploy@yourhost.com}
```